# Why does numpy array comparison return boolean array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Why does:

```
[3] == np.arange(10)
```

return:

```
([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Instead of simply `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does `np.arange(10)+3` return an array?  The comparison `[3] == np.arange(10)` is treating the arguments in the same way, element by element (with broadcasting as needed).

If it can't broadcast and do element wise comparison it does return a False or an error.

```
In [285]: np.arange(10)==[1,2]
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[285]: False
```